# Buiding a Docker image with a external project reference (outside solution)

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm having trouble building a Docker Image of my project. In my project I have a project reference from an application, which is not in the same solution as my project. When I try to build my Docker image I get the following errors/warnings:

```
PS C:\Trunk\Tools\Dashboard> docker build -f Server/Dockerfile --force-rm  -t dashboardserver .
[+] Building 228.2s (15/17)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 579B                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0                                                                                                                                          0.9s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0@sha256:a2a8f968b043349b8faa0625c5405ac33da70b3274ff9e17109430f16aa9a3ee                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                          2.2s
 => => transferring context: 1.32MB                                                                                                                                                                        2.2s
 => CACHED [base 2/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [final 1/2] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [build 3/7] COPY [Server/Server.csproj, Server/]                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "Server/Server.csproj"                                                                                                                                                 94.6s
 => [build 5/7] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/Server                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                                                                                                          102.3s
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#15 3.459 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET
#15 3.459 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#15 3.459
#15 4.336   Determining projects to restore...
#15 4.341   Skipping project "/SomeApp/Api/SomeApp.Api.csproj" because it was not found.
#15 4.343   Skipping project "/SomeApp/Api/SomeApp.Api.csproj" because it was not found.
#15 4.729   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#15 5.139 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2065,5): warning : The referenced project '../../../SomeApp/Api/SomeApp.Api.csproj' does not exist. [/src/Server/Server.csproj]
#15 97.00 /src/Server/Program.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SomeApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/Server/Server.csproj]
#15 98.57
#15 98.57 Build FAILED.
#15 98.57
#15 98.57 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.201/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2065,5): warning : The referenced project '../../../SomeApp/Api/SomeApp.Api.csproj' does not exist. [/src/Server/Server.csproj]
#15 98.57 /src/Server/Program.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SomeApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/src/Server/Server.csproj]
#15 98.57     1 Warning(s)
#15 98.57     1 Error(s)
#15 98.57
#15 98.57 Time Elapsed 00:01:35.02
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
```

The Dockerfile which is used:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server/Server.csproj", "Server/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server/Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
EXPOSE 5004
```

The directory looks as follows:

```
\Trunk\Tools\Dashboard (my application with its own solution) 
\Trunk\SomeApp (other application with its own solution)  
    +- SomeApp.sln  
    +- Api ("project" folder) 
            +- SomeApp.Api.csproj
```

Project reference in dashboard.sln:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\SomeApp\Api\SomeApp.Api.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried to build a Docker image of my application, and I expected to get a Docker image, so I could build a Docker container. I totally get that it can't find the 'SomeApp' application, because I'm not pushing it to the Docker image. But how could I solve this problem?

(Edit: removed unreadable JPG and added cmd lines. Also added Dockerfile, which is used at the moment. For the minimal reproducible example there are two project solutions needed, with the same file structure as shown above. )

Comment: That PNG file is very hard to read.  Can you [edit] the question to delete it and replace it with the actual text of the build output?  Usually an error message on its own isn't enough to debug an issue and it'd also help to include a [mcve] with enough source code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze I editted the original post. Hope this is better.